# declaring a function in polymer

Tags: function, polymer, declaration

I'm trying to use a function within another, but even though I declared it beforehand, polymer says it isn't. I don't get it. any clue?

```
Polymer({
is: 'x-foo',

//some other code here, including the properties....

computeRange: function (offset, limit, nodeRangeStart, nodeRangeEnd) {
  nodeRangeStart.innerText = offset;
  nodeRangeEnd.innerText = offset + limit;
},
prevPage: function () {
  this.offset = this.offset - this.limit;
  computeRange(this.offset, this.limit, this.$.usersListRangeStart, this.$.usersListRangeEnd);
  this.$.nextPage.removeAttribute('disabled');
  if (this.offset <= 0) {
    this.$.prevPage.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    this.$.prevPage.style.color = '#DDDDDD';
  };
}

});
```

and the console:

Uncaught ReferenceError: computeRange is not defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're attempting to call `computeRange()` as if it were a global function, but it's actually part of your constructor object. You'll need to use `this`:

```
this.computeRange(...)
```

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thank you very much, tony!